# Python parameter name deprecated

Tags: python, parameters, alias, keyword-argument, positional-argument

I'm currently working on a project I cannot release a breaking code, i.e., function names must remain the same, the same applies to its parameters and everything else into the code. With this being said, people usually call functions with positional parameters as keyword parameters e.g.

```py
def foo(a):
    ...
foo(a=2)
```

The problem is I have to change the parameter name, and it might break the code when calling the function with positional arguments as it was meant to be:

```py
def foo(a, b, c=3, d=5):
    ...
foo(3,4) # works
foo(a=3,b=4) # works

# After renaming 'a'
def foo(ax, b, c=3, d=5):
    ...
foo(3,4) #works
foo(a=3, b=4) # doesn't work
```

I tried to add **kwargs, however, it doesn't solve all problems

```py
def foo(b, ax=None, c=3, d=5, **kwargs):
    if 'a' in kwargs:
        warn('\'a\' is deprecated, use \'ax\' instead')
        ax = kwargs['a']
    assert ax is not None, "ax cannot be None"
    ...
foo(a=3, b=4) # works
foo(ax=3, b=4) # works
foo(3,4) #doesn't work
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: First you say that function names and their parameters must not change. Then you say you want to do exactly that. If within the function the new name `ax` would have the same functionality as `a`, I see no reason why you'd need to change that.

Comment: Sorry, I meant they must not change in order of not to break the code, it actually means the function must stay working as it was, and not I cannot strictly change it. However, to improve legibility I want to change `a` to `ax`.

Comment: @NickolasdaRochaMachado Have you found a solution? I'm having the same problem and I've found https://stackoverflow.com/a/49803213/9266726. I haven't tried it but in dry-reading it looks correct. I'd expect a canonical protocol to exist, as this must happen all the time.